# iphone Feed Type Text with Hyperlinks

Tags: iphone, text, uitableview, hyperlink

Im creating a tableview that displays a feed similar to the facebook iphone app news feed. Im just wondering what control i should use in my custom table cell that will allow me to show a mixture of text and hyperlinks. e.g. UserA has just sent you a message. Where "UserA" is a hyperlink and when the user clicks on it I need to be able to catch that event and send them to UserA's details.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may want to take a page directly from facebook's well.. book.  http://www.three20.info (look at UICatalog and how he does this there)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid putting individual touchable elements into the cells. It can become confusing if there is different functionality depending on where the user taps.

Can you just catch the selection of the cell and perform the appropriate action then?

Comment: There are some instances where there will be more than one link per cell.